# How to count exact matches considering the leading zeros in Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba, leading-zero, exact-match

I have a project called inventory number generator. The numbers are for each element of each stock group which includes 2 digits for main product groups, 2 digits for sub product groups, 2 digits for component groups and in total they form the first 6 digits of the inventory number. The following 3 digits are for the individual element number which I am trying to generate after the count of a given stock group numbers exact matches in the inventory number list and by adding 1 to the count result.

`_ _  _ _  _ _  _ _ _`

`M G  S G  C G  I E N`

```
MG = Main Group

SG = Sub Group

CG = Component Group

SG = Stock Group (The First 6 Digits)

IEN = Individual Element Number
```

The problem here is that each group number can contain leading zeros or each digit can be zero. To create the unique numbers, I need to count the exact matches of the given stock group (which is actually the combined version of the 3 groups) by searching it in the inventory number list and to add a new inventory number which is created by adding 1 to the count result and adding that result which has maximum 3 digits to the end of the stock groups 6 digits. After creating them I also add them to the inventory number list. For example if the given stock group is "00 00 10" and if the inventory number list has inventory numbers like "00 00 00 010" then the counter counts them too.

Note: The numbers don't have spaces (" ") between them I put them there to make it easier to understand.

Here are the codes that I wrote:

```
Private Sub EkleSEB_Click() 'Stok Ekle kısmında Stok Ekle butonu tıklanırsa

Dim StokSS As Variant 'Stok Ekle Sıra Say
Dim StokS As Variant 'Stok Say
Dim StokEAS As Integer 'Stok Eşleşen Adet Say
Dim StokG As Long 'Stok Grubu
Dim StokA As Long

If AnaGKSEC <> "" And AltGKSEC <> "" And BilGKSEC <> "" And BirSEC <> "" And StokASET <> "" Then

    StokSS = WorksheetFunction.CountA(Worksheets("ÜretimKodları").Range("A:A")) + 1

    StokG = (AltGKSEC.Value * 100) + BilGKSEC.Value

    For StokS = 2 To StokSS

        If Len(Left(ThisWorkbook.Sheets("ÜretimKodları").Cells(StokS, 1).Value, 9)) < 4 And StokG = 0 Then

            StokEAS = (Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Worksheets("ÜretimKodları").Range("A2", ThisWorkbook.Sheets("ÜretimKodları").Cells(StokSS - 1, 1)), "<1000")) + 1

            If StokEAS = 999 Then

                MsgBox "Seçilen grupta kod sınırına ulaşıldı!"

            Else 'Stok Kodu oluştur

                Worksheets("ÜretimKodları").Cells(StokSS, 1) = Format(((StokG * 1000) + StokEAS), "#########000000000")
                Worksheets("ÜretimKodları").Cells(StokSS, 2) = StokASET.Value
                Worksheets("ÜretimKodları").Cells(StokSS, 3) = BirSEC.Value
                StokKSET.Value = Format(Worksheets("ÜretimKodları").Cells(StokSS, 1).Value, "#########000000000")

            End If

        ElseIf Len(Left(ThisWorkbook.Sheets("ÜretimKodları").Cells(StokS, 1).Value, 9)) = 4 And StokG > 0 And StokG < 10 Then

            StokEAS = 0

            For StokA = 2 To StokSS - 1

                If Left(ThisWorkbook.Sheets("ÜretimKodları").Cells(StokA, 1).Value, 1) = Left(StokG, 1) Then

                StokEAS = StokEAS + 1

                End If

            Next StokA

            If StokEAS = 999 Then

                MsgBox "Seçilen grupta kod sınırına ulaşıldı!"

            Else 'Stok Kodu oluştur

                Worksheets("ÜretimKodları").Cells(StokSS, 1) = Format(((StokG * 1000) + StokEAS + 1), "#########000000000")
                Worksheets("ÜretimKodları").Cells(StokSS, 2) = StokASET.Value
                Worksheets("ÜretimKodları").Cells(StokSS, 3) = BirSEC.Value
                StokKSET.Value = Format(Worksheets("ÜretimKodları").Cells(StokSS, 1).Value, "#########000000000")

            End If

        ElseIf Len(Left(ThisWorkbook.Sheets("ÜretimKodları").Cells(StokS, 1).Value, 9)) = 5 And StokG > 9 And StokG < 100 Then

            For StokA = 2 To StokSS - 1

                If Left(ThisWorkbook.Sheets("ÜretimKodları").Cells(StokA, 1).Value, 2) = Left(StokG, 2) Then

                StokEAS = StokEAS + 1

                End If

            Next StokA

            If StokEAS = 999 Then

                MsgBox "Seçilen grupta kod sınırına ulaşıldı!"

            Else 'Stok Kodu oluştur

                Worksheets("ÜretimKodları").Cells(StokSS, 1) = Format(((StokG * 1000) + StokEAS), "#########000000000")
                Worksheets("ÜretimKodları").Cells(StokSS, 2) = StokASET.Value
                Worksheets("ÜretimKodları").Cells(StokSS, 3) = BirSEC.Value
                StokKSET.Value = Format(Worksheets("ÜretimKodları").Cells(StokSS, 1).Value, "#########000000000")

            End If

        ElseIf Len(Left(ThisWorkbook.Sheets("ÜretimKodları").Cells(StokS, 1).Value, 9)) = 6 And StokG > 99 And StokG < 1000 Then

            For StokA = 2 To StokSS - 1

                If Left(ThisWorkbook.Sheets("ÜretimKodları").Cells(StokA, 1).Value, 3) = Left(StokG, 3) Then

                StokEAS = StokEAS + 1

                End If

            Next StokA

            If StokEAS = 999 Then

                MsgBox "Seçilen grupta kod sınırına ulaşıldı!"

            Else 'Stok Kodu oluştur

                Worksheets("ÜretimKodları").Cells(StokSS, 1) = Format(((StokG * 1000) + StokEAS), "#########000000000")
                Worksheets("ÜretimKodları").Cells(StokSS, 2) = StokASET.Value
                Worksheets("ÜretimKodları").Cells(StokSS, 3) = BirSEC.Value
                StokKSET.Value = Format(Worksheets("ÜretimKodları").Cells(StokSS, 1).Value, "#########000000000")

            End If

        ElseIf Len(Left(ThisWorkbook.Sheets("ÜretimKodları").Cells(StokS, 1).Value, 9)) = 7 And StokG > 999 And StokG < 10000 Then

            For StokA = 2 To StokSS - 1

                If Left(ThisWorkbook.Sheets("ÜretimKodları").Cells(StokA, 1).Value, 4) = Left(StokG, 4) Then

                StokEAS = StokEAS + 1

                End If

            Next StokA

            If StokEAS = 999 Then

                MsgBox "Seçilen grupta kod sınırına ulaşıldı!"

            Else 'Stok Kodu oluştur

                Worksheets("ÜretimKodları").Cells(StokSS, 1) = Format(((StokG * 1000) + StokEAS), "#########000000000")
                Worksheets("ÜretimKodları").Cells(StokSS, 2) = StokASET.Value
                Worksheets("ÜretimKodları").Cells(StokSS, 3) = BirSEC.Value
                StokKSET.Value = Format(Worksheets("ÜretimKodları").Cells(StokSS, 1).Value, "#########000000000")

            End If

        ElseIf Len(Left(ThisWorkbook.Sheets("ÜretimKodları").Cells(StokS, 1).Value, 9)) = 8 And StokG > 9999 And StokG < 100000 Then

            For StokA = 2 To StokSS - 1

                If Left(ThisWorkbook.Sheets("ÜretimKodları").Cells(StokA, 1).Value, 5) = Left(StokG, 5) Then

                StokEAS = StokEAS + 1

                End If

            Next StokA

            If StokEAS = 999 Then

                MsgBox "Seçilen grupta kod sınırına ulaşıldı!"

            Else 'Stok Kodu oluştur

                Worksheets("ÜretimKodları").Cells(StokSS, 1) = Format(((StokG * 1000) + StokEAS), "#########000000000")
                Worksheets("ÜretimKodları").Cells(StokSS, 2) = StokASET.Value
                Worksheets("ÜretimKodları").Cells(StokSS, 3) = BirSEC.Value
                StokKSET.Value = Format(Worksheets("ÜretimKodları").Cells(StokSS, 1).Value, "#########000000000")

            End If

        ElseIf Len(Left(ThisWorkbook.Sheets("ÜretimKodları").Cells(StokS, 1).Value, 9)) = 9 And StokG > 99999 And StokG < 1000000 Then

            For StokA = 2 To StokSS - 1

                If Left(ThisWorkbook.Sheets("ÜretimKodları").Cells(StokA, 1).Value, 6) = Left(StokG, 6) Then

                StokEAS = StokEAS + 1

                End If

            Next StokA

            If StokEAS = 999 Then

                MsgBox "Seçilen grupta kod sınırına ulaşıldı!"

            Else 'Stok Kodu oluştur

                Worksheets("ÜretimKodları").Cells(StokSS, 1) = Format(((StokG * 1000) + StokEAS), "#########000000000")
                Worksheets("ÜretimKodları").Cells(StokSS, 2) = StokASET.Value
                Worksheets("ÜretimKodları").Cells(StokSS, 3) = BirSEC.Value
                StokKSET.Value = Format(Worksheets("ÜretimKodları").Cells(StokSS, 1).Value, "#########000000000")

            End If

        Else

            Worksheets("ÜretimKodları").Cells(StokSS, 1) = Format(((StokG * 1000) + StokEAS), "#########000000000")
            Worksheets("ÜretimKodları").Cells(StokSS, 2) = StokASET.Value
            Worksheets("ÜretimKodları").Cells(StokSS, 3) = BirSEC.Value
            StokKSET.Value = Format(Worksheets("ÜretimKodları").Cells(StokSS, 1).Value, "#########000000000")

        End If

    Next StokS

Else

    MsgBox "Tüm alanları Doldurun!"

End If

End Sub
```

As you see I sorted each element on the list by the place of the first non-zero digit they have but the only thing I couldn't do is to make the "Left()" function to count the leading zeros or I need a new function to count the exact matches considering the leading zeros.

Edit:

I don't know actually in which type they are stored but I fromatted the Inventory Lists' first column in which the 9 digit Inventory Numbers are stored with special formatting. I will try to shortly explain the way I am trying to create a new Inventory Number for a new element. So first the user adds new Product Groups in a userform tab and then related to the Product Group, they add new SubProduct Groups in another userform tab. The Component Groups are added also in another userform tab but they are not related to the Product-SubProduct Groups. So at the end the user adds a new Inventory Number in the last userform tab by selecting a Product Group from a combobox and then they choose depending on the selection of a Product Group, from a second dependent combobox the SubProduct Group. After that they select a Component Group from an indepenent combobox and they give a name to the new element. So the Product and SubProduct Groups are combined and listed in the SubProduct Group combobox with their descriptions beside their numbers. By adding the 4 digits from the Product-SubProduct Groups and the 2 digits from the Component Group combobox selections we have our Stock Group Number which has 6 digits, as an input. The real deal was to find the given Stock Group number in the Inventory List which is formatted to show 9 digits and has leading zeros and to count the exact matches. By adding 1 to the count result we create our new Element or Inventory Number.

Edit 2:

The problems I solved with a new formula:

1. If the firs row is empty than the match() function crashes
2. If the Stock Group number is "0" than the match() function doesn't work eighter.
3. The problem with adding a number to the list which contains less digits than the previous one than the match() function focuses on the last added number or the number which contains less digits is solved.

4.I also added a function which stops adding a new Inventory Number to the list (wile in my case a Stock Group can have only 999 elements) when the counter hits "999".

And the new VBA Code: (Sorry for the Turkish comments that you see in the codes)

```
Private Sub EkleSEB_Click() 'Stok Ekle kısmında Stok Ekle butonu tıklanırsa

Dim StokK As Variant 'Stok Kodu
Dim StokKS As Variant 'Stok Kodu Say
Dim StokSS As Variant 'Stok Sıra Say
Dim StokG As Variant 'Stok Grubu
Dim StokGF As Variant 'Stok Grubu Formatlı
Dim StokGS As Variant 'Stok Grubu Say

If AnaGKSEC <> "" And AltGKSEC <> "" And BilGKSEC <> "" And BirSEC <> "" And StokASET <> "" Then

    StokSS = WorksheetFunction.CountA(Worksheets("ÜretimKodları").Range("A:A")) + 1

    StokG = ((AltGKSEC.Value * 100) + BilGKSEC.Value)

    StokGF = Format(StokG, "000000")

    StokKS = 0

    For StokGS = 2 To StokSS 'Stok Grubu Say

        If StokGF = Left(Worksheets("ÜretimKodları").Cells(StokGS, 1).Text, 6) Then

            StokKS = StokKS + 1

        End If

    Next StokGS

    If Not StokKS > 999 Then

        StokK = (StokG * 1000) + StokKS 'Stok Kodu Oluştur

        Worksheets("ÜretimKodları").Cells(StokSS, 1) = Format(StokK, "#########000000000")
        Worksheets("ÜretimKodları").Cells(StokSS, 2) = StokASET.Value
        Worksheets("ÜretimKodları").Cells(StokSS, 3) = BirSEC.Value

        StokKSET.Value = Format(Worksheets("ÜretimKodları").Cells(StokSS, 1).Value, "#########000000000")

    Else

        MsgBox "Seçtiğiniz Grup Kodu İçin Üretilebilecek Stok Kodu Sınırına Ulaşıldı!"

    End If

Else

    MsgBox "Tüm alanları Doldurun!"

End If

End Sub
```

Comment: How are these numbers stored? Are these stored as text/strings or are these stored as true numbers with a number format fixed to 9 digits? • Second question: Is your data sorted by this number?

Comment: Sorry for the late response (I live in Germany). I think that they are stored as numbers but when I use the Left() funtion they turn into strings right? But I edited the question so that you can understand the procedure better. Can you please tell me how I can see the type of the variables in VBA? Thank you so much.

Comment: Well you are the only one who can tell if the "numbers" are actually stored as text/strings or as numeric values. *"I think"* doesn't help us to help you, we need to know it for sure because it make a huge difference. • Also I cannot give you a full solution. The question is a way to broad. But I could give you only an example how it would work with numeric values (see my answer).

Answer (score 0):

If you use real numbers as inventory numbers (and not text/strings) you can do the following:

[image]

- Column A contains true numbers formatted with number format `00 00 00 000` for easy visability. The actual number that is stored in the cells in column A is shown in column B.
- Column F has the formulas shown in column I, they result of these formulas is a true number as shown in column G. Column F is just formatted with a number format too.

The user has to input the full 6 digit group number in F3 (red) and the formulas will give you the next free inventory number of that group in F9 (green).

Comment: In VBA you could use the [WorksheetFunction.Match method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.worksheetfunction.match) and the [WorksheetFunction.Index method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.worksheetfunction.index) as equivalent for the formulas. What exactly do you mean by *"I was stuck by formatting the values into numbers"*? Could you add a screenshot of your data into the original question?

Comment: Sorry about he first comment (Internet connection lost). Thank you for your efforts and quick response. I would be very thankful if you could help me to solve this problem without adding a new column but only changing the code in VBA. The real problem with this code was to take the formatted values from the cells and use them in a function so that they could be counted as they keep the format. So I couldn't find a solution to use the formatted values in any type of count function so I tried to count the leading zeros to create a new counting formula but at the end the leading zeros beat me :)

Comment: @HakanTosun Sorry I cannot fix your code. The question you ask is too broad. The example above is probably the best example how you would do it. • Please note that I did not add any new column. Column B just illustrates the real value that is actually in column A (which is formatted by numberformat `00 00 00 000` only). Column B is not used at all in my example it is just for illustration. Column A and B are exactly the same value.

Comment: By the way I was thinking a similar solution as yours but I didn't want to change the visuals but only the code so that I could perhaps store the actual numbers in a variable or I don't know actually how to store multiple values like a range of values in a variable. Is Range a variable type? If yes, do I have to link the variable to an actual range in excel sheet or are the values stored in elsewhere?

Comment: I got my answer but I didn't want you to change my code. You already solved my problem. Thank you again for everything. You are faster than my toughts :)

Comment: If your cells contain true numbers you don't need to change anything on your cells. Just put into VBA code what I illustrated in the formulas thats all.

Comment: One more question: I need to check if the last 3 digits or Element Number of a Stock Group hits "999" then i need to stop adding new Inventory Numbers because then it will effect the Stock Group section. Can you help me with this problem, too?

Comment: Your code was almost perfect for me. I tuned it a little bit and adjusted it for my project. I am goin to share the edited version of it at the end of my question. Thank you very much.

Comment: Just check in my example if `F9 - F4 < 1000` to limit it to 999.

Comment: The code has some bugs. If I add a number which has less digits after any number which contains more digits than the added one, the match() function is focusing on the number which contains less digits or to the new added number. But I think we are getting closer to the solution thanks to you.

Comment: @HakanTosun Can you give an example dataset in your original question? I either didn't understand what you mean or cannot reproduce it. Note that this approach assumes sorted data in column A. Otherwise the match fails.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you but I found the solution that I was looking for by myself  :D

P.S.: The codes that I am sharing here includes Turkish comments that I wrote and they are tuned for my project but if you have any questions just ask.

Here are the codes for counting exact matches in a specified range of digits from the beginning of the numbers even though they have leading zeros:

```
Private Sub EkleSEB_Click() 'Stok Ekle kısmında Stok Ekle butonu tıklanırsa

Dim StokK As Variant 'Stok Kodu
Dim StokKS As Variant 'Stok Kodu Say
Dim StokSS As Variant 'Stok Sıra Say
Dim StokG As Variant 'Stok Grubu
Dim StokGF As Variant 'Stok Grubu Formatlı
Dim StokGS As Variant 'Stok Grubu Say

If AnaGKSEC <> "" And AltGKSEC <> "" And BilGKSEC <> "" And BirSEC <> "" And StokASET <> "" Then

    StokSS = WorksheetFunction.CountA(Worksheets("ÜretimKodları").Range("A:A")) + 1

    StokG = ((AltGKSEC.Value * 100) + BilGKSEC.Value)

    StokGF = Format(StokG, "000000")

    StokKS = 0

    For StokGS = 2 To StokSS 'Stok Grubu Say

        If StokGF = Left(Worksheets("ÜretimKodları").Cells(StokGS, 1).Text, 6) Then

            StokKS = StokKS + 1

        End If

    Next StokGS

    StokK = (StokG * 1000) + StokKS 'Stok Kodu Oluştur

    Worksheets("ÜretimKodları").Cells(StokSS, 1) = Format(StokK, "#########000000000")
    Worksheets("ÜretimKodları").Cells(StokSS, 2) = StokASET.Value
    Worksheets("ÜretimKodları").Cells(StokSS, 3) = BirSEC.Value

    StokKSET.Value = Format(Worksheets("ÜretimKodları").Cells(StokSS, 1).Value, "#########000000000")

Else

    MsgBox "Tüm alanları Doldurun!"

End If

End Sub
```